# llvmc: Can't find program 'llvm-g++'

Tags: llvm

I am getting this error while using the command "llvmc -O3 -Wall hello.cpp" where hello.cpp is some cpp file on my machine. llvmc is the driver calling a bunch of tools like llvm-g++, opt, llc etc. I think the llvmc tool could not probably locate the llvm-g++ tool. I would like to know where should I specify the path to llvm-g++ for llvmc to find them. Also can someone give me the link to some tutorial on llvmc because i couldn't find it on llvm.org webpage. My llvmc is in /llvm/tools/llvmc. While llvm-g++ is inside /llvm/Debug/bin/.

thanks.

Answer (score 0):

IIRC, llvmc just use your PATH environment variable, so you should set it to /path/to/llvm/Debug/bin:$PATH

Also take a look at llvmc --help output, there should be a flag to set path to llvm-g++.

Be aware that llvmc have been removed in LLVM 3.0.

Answer (score 0):

If you are not restricted to gcc frontend, try to compile with `clang` . `clang` uses llvm as backend as well (so you can `--emit-llvm` if you like).

Answer (score 0):

If you cannot use clang, you might want to use DragonEgg [at llvm](http://dragonegg.llvm.org/)